# Get The Display Name of Xorg The Correct Way?

Tags: x11, xorg

I have to get the display_name variable of an Xorg Display struct. (eg. display->display_name).

Right now I'm compiling with the XLIB_ILLEGAL_ACCESS define, which gives me direct access to the struct.

Is there a proper way to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need `DisplayString(dpy)` - see [xdpyinfo source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xdpyinfo/tree/xdpyinfo.c#n239).

Comment: Yes, see http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Display_Macros for a list of macros to access the various fields from the Xlib Display struct.

Comment: Yeah, I'm blind. Thanks.